# Kernel Module Init and Exit functions being called in wrong order

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, kernel-module

I'm making a very simple hello world kernel module and getting some crazy behavior.  This worked until I upgraded to kernel 3.3.8 and now it... Well, it's calling the `init` function on exit, and the `exit` function on initialize.  I've made sure my names are correct

```
// Needed for module definitions
#include <linux/module.h>
// Needed for initilization modules
#include <linux/init.h>

// Must declare some license
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

// Function to be called on insmod
// Returns 0 on success
static int __init mymod_init(void)
{
        // Prints kernel alert.  Check /var/log/syslog
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Module was loaded, this is the printk.");

        return 0;
}

// Function to be called on rmmod
static void __exit mymod_exit(void)
{
        // Prints kernel alert.  Check /var/log/syslog
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Module was unloaded, this is the printk");
}

// Register these functions
module_init(mymod_init);
module_exit(mymod_exit);
```

Sample output:

> root@cop4610:/home/cop4610/Downloads/linux-3.3.8/mymodule# insmod
>   mymodule.ko root@cop4610:/home/cop4610/Downloads/linux-3.3.8/mymodule#
>   tail /var/log/syslog Oct 12 10:08:20 cop4610 kernel: [  633.567832]
>   Module was unloaded, this is the printk

The following is a video of this happening live:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aJNSpCd7as&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Have you made rebuild for your module after upgrade?

Comment: I've remade it from scratch since the kernel upgrade ;)

Comment: are __init and __exit macro now optional?

Comment: I've tried adding them with no luck, edited my original post

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It needed a newline!!!!!! Arrggg!!!

```
 printk(KERN_ALERT "Module was unloaded, this is the printk\n");
```

and

```
 printk(KERN_ALERT "Module was loaded, this is the printk\n");
```

It seems it wasn't really doing them out of order, it just appeared to, because the first one was not showing up until the second one was issued as the buffer was not flushed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. I was having the same problem and was perplexed. It makes sense now after seeing your answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution.

Comment: was facing issue, I cant thank you enough for this

Answer (score 1):

This is my basic example:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

#define MODULE_NAME "hello_md"

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("B3h3m0th");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Basic LKM; hello world module");
MODULE_VERSION("0.0");

static int __init insert_mod(void)
{
   printk(KERN_ALERT "[%s] Init: \"Hello World\"\n", MODULE_NAME);
   return 0;
}


static void __exit remove_mod(void)
{
   printk(KERN_ALERT "[%s] Exit\n", MODULE_NAME);
}

module_init(insert_mod);
module_exit(remove_mod);
```

My basic Makefile:

```
obj-m += basic_module.o 

KERNELVERSION = $(shell uname -r)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(KERNELVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(KERNELVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```